# SwitchCompat no longer support API 9

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat, switchcompat

As of Support Library `25.3.0` the [SwitchCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SwitchCompat.html) widget requires API 14 and higher. They say it is fixed in `25.3.1` but I am using `25.4.0` and this is not fixed.

I have tried to copy the old [SwitchCompat.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/b49560d4675f87b917a6710dfe03ebcde76d9996/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/widget/SwitchCompat.java) file to my project but there is methods and classes that is package-private and cannot be used outside the support library.

There were some vital changes and additions in the latest support library version therefore I can't switch back to older version. What can I do to bring the `SwitchCompat` widget to Android 2.3.3?

Comment: The whole of the Android Support Library has a `minSdkVersion` of 14 starting with `26.0.0`. So, in the not-too-distant future, you need to either drop support for Android 2.x, stop using the Support Library (particularly things like `appcompat-v7`), or plan to maintain your own fork of the Library. Tactically... when you copied the class into your project, did you leave it in the `android.support.v7.widget` package? You'll need to rename it (`SwitchCompatCompat`, perhaps?), and switch to it in your layouts and stuff. But package-private things work so long as the class is in the same package.

Comment: @CommonsWare Renaiming the class did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I am receiving extra money from the employer for the Android 2.3.3 support!